# Font looks better in chrome than firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I was testing my web app on my browsers, but when I tested it on firefox, the font (Lato) looks ugly than Chrome. How can I fix it ? Thanks.

*EDIT*: I'm talking about `Connexion` button.

**font rendering on chrome:**

[image: font rendering on Chrome]

**font rendering on firefox:**

[image]

Comment: Looks like the first two has different fonts loaded in FF. Are you talking about `Pseudo` or `Connexion`?

Comment: I am talking about `Connexion`, `pseudo` actually looks good

Comment: Guessed. I have a fix for that. But the crazy thing works opposite for me.

Comment: Give me your fix, I will test if it works :p

Comment: Given. Check and tell me if it works. `:)`

Comment: Inspect the button in Firefox and check the Computed and Fonts section to see if that is the font that is actually used, or if it's being replaced by something else because it could find or load it correctly.

Comment: Are you using any font-weight? Normally setting it to normal fixes it.

Comment: Just tried now @PraveenKumar

Comment: @timss oh, the font is lato, i didn't see that 
but I replaced it with ubuntu condensed, same problem, the font is really better in chrome

Answer (score 2):

First solution: **Text Shadow trick**:

```css
.affected_ff {text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
```

Then try, **Font Smoothing**:

```css
html {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; font-smoothing: antialiased;}
```

Final fix, **Translate3D**:

```css
.affected_ff {transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
```

Comment: There's a little change, but It's not smooth like chrome :(
http://i.imgur.com/lZGXpDl.png

Comment: @MrZrn Try adding more... Say, `{text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}` - Try this?

Comment: Tried, always same problem :/

Comment: @MrZrn That's the best I could say bro... Show me your code in CSS? The font inclusion...

Comment: What's with you and screenshotting all the codes? Whatever, generally Google Fonts are meant to render legibly...

Comment: Sorry for that man, I just can't paste all the code on a comment, and I hasn't thought for pastebin, so I've made a screenshot